# Problems using libvirt to create a Win98 Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, windows-98, libvirt

Recently, I encountered a need to run some Windows 98 software.  I decided to use this project to learn about virtual machines (I have had no previous experience).  I tried to run virtualbox on my Fedora 31 system, but I found that this required newly compiled modules which would have to be signed to be usable on my UEFI Secure Boot system.  I therefore next turned to libvirt.

Installation on libvirt was fairly easy.  libvirt apparently recognized Windows 98 SE as one of its emulation options, and installation of my Win98 disk went smoothly.  However, the installed system would not boot.  After starting up the virtual machine, the screen went black and never changed.

Searching for help, I found a recommendation for using basic qemu commands.  Based on this, I tried launching the virtual machine with:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda /var/lib/ghb/qemu/images/win98.qcow2 -drive media=cdrom,format=raw,file=/data/ghb/Projects/QIC/qicstruc/windows98se.iso -no-kvm -vga cirrus -m 256 -cpu pentium3 -rtc base=localtime
```

This worked!  After installation, the virtual machine behaved like I expected.  I then tried to go back and change the libvirt machine by using virsh edit.  I change domain type to qemu and arch to i686.  Trying to change machine to pentium3, virsh objected saying the the IDE controller was incompatible with that combination of options.  Nevertheless,I attempted to install with the accepted options.  Again, installation went smoothly and this time the machine booted successfully.  However, the mouse was so sluggish as to be unusable.

From all the libvirt documentation I can find, I get the impression that libvirt is primarily concerned with migration between hosts, and only secondarily with emulation of other (and particularly obsolete) hardware.  I also get the impression that qemu offers a wider range of configuration options than libvirt.  I was primarily interested in libvirt because it was easier to use than qemu.  However, since I am unlikely to ever use migration, am I wasting my time learning about libvirt?

Comment: You probably ran into trouble when you tried to *change* the Win98 machine to go "back to the future."  Better to start with a brand new VM definition.

Comment: Well, I *think* I understood what you were trying to do ... maybe I did, maybe I didn't. If I got it wrong just disregard my last comment.  Also, there can be fairly-general problems involved with running 32-bit VMs on today's 64-bit hardware.

Comment: Virtual Box does not fully support Windows 98. Perhaps consider VMware. I have a working Windows 98 box in VMware V15.  "Unfortunately VirtualBox once again provides limited support for Windows 98, so the Guest Additions isn’t going to be of use ..."  Quote from an Oracle thread

Comment: Guest Additions isn't really necessary for normal usage. (VirtualBox still handles old Windows versions better than qemu-kvm does.)

Answer (score 0):

Qemu-system-x86_64 defaults to the Q35 machine type and qemu-system- i386 defaults to the PC machine type. The Q35 uses a Sata controller and it will Install but refuse to run after the install due to driver issues.

My recommendation is to use the AMD/LSI SCSI controller instead of IDE for either machine type.

By default Dos/Win9x runs fine with either 64bit or 32 bit qemu, however you can't switch between machine types without a reinstall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have to, you can force PATA by adding an IDE drive specification. Although the 64-bit VM may default to SATA, libvirt is still going to automatically add a PATA controller when it encounters an IDE drive declaration within the domain definition, however, the OS in use also has to bring the necessary drivers for it to work.